# ALSA: Couldn't open audio device: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pygame, alsa, mixer

If I start my python program as root (I have to start it as root cause the keyboard-module) this problem accrued:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Stopping program
Stopping program
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/run.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "[...]/run.py", line 11, in main
    GameStateManager.change_gamestate(SetupState())
  File "[...]/src/game_state.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.setup_sound_manager()
  File "[...]/src/game_state.py", line 110, in setup_sound_manager
    GameState.sound_manager = SoundManager()
  File "[...]/src/utils.py", line 253, in __init__
    mixer.init()
pygame.error: ALSA: Couldn't open audio device: No such file or directory
```

If I run a a sound manually with `sudo aplay test.wav` than this error comes up:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
```

**System**

```
                    /-                      
                   ooo:                     ----------------------------
                  yoooo/                    OS: ArcoLinux
                 yooooooo                   Kernel: 5.17.4-arch1-1
                yooooooooo                  Uptime: 3 days, 23 hours, 2 mins
               yooooooooooo                 Packages: 1373 (pacman)
             .yooooooooooooo                Shell: zsh 5.8.1
            .oooooooooooooooo               Resolution: 1920x1080
           .oooooooarcoooooooo              WM: i3
          .ooooooooo-oooooooooo             Theme: Arc-Dark [GTK2/3]
         .ooooooooo-  oooooooooo            Icons: Sardi-Arc [GTK2/3]
        :ooooooooo.    :ooooooooo           Terminal: alacritty
       :ooooooooo.      :ooooooooo          CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (8) @ 2.000GHz
      :oooarcooo         .oooarcooo         GPU: AMD ATI Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series
     :ooooooooy           .ooooooooo        Memory: 2015MiB / 6904MiB (29%)
    :ooooooooo   /ooooooooooooooooooo
   :ooooooooo      .-ooooooooooooooooo.
  ooooooooo-             -ooooooooooooo.
 ooooooooo-                 .-oooooooooo.
ooooooooo.                     -ooooooooo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give full path of your sound file. Such as:

```
your/full/path/to/file/test.wav
```

If this didn't work, Your SDL default sound driver is `alsa`. You can change your sound driver using this command:

```
import os
os.environ['SDL_AUDIODRIVER'] = 'dsp'
# Your code
```

Put these two lines very top of your code.

Comment: Nope, does not work. The problem is, that alsa is not able to find the device, like a sound-card. If I did understood it correctly

Comment: Edited the answer. You can try changing your sound driver.

Comment: Second doesn't work either.
`mixer.init() -> pygame.error`

Comment: Add `pygame.init()` command after importing pygame.

Comment: No. I just want to init the mixer. I do not need the other modules.

Comment: You can use `pygame.mixer.init()` to only init the mixer module.

Comment: Yes, this is, what i am doing.

Answer (score 0):

You MUST initialize pygame using `pygame.init()` to use the mixer.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I did initialize the mixer. It semes like the problem is on the OS site. I did changed from ArcoLinux to Manjaro. Here i didn't had a problem like this.